# How to change textfield border style in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, border

I want to change only bottom border style. Is it possible? I know this code

```
theTextFiels.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor]CGColor]; // border rengi
theTextFiels.layer.borderWidth= 5.0f; // border kalınlığı
```

but this apply the changes to all borders (up, right, left, bottom)
How can I change the only bottom border color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you won't be able to change only one side border color unless you subclass and know you way around in draw rect method of UIView.

You should try @stiles way ..making a image and then setting it as background...

Steps are :
Make four images ; each with a different side as a color border you want.
Then change the text field background to the appropriate one.

You should make the images as similar as to original text field ..this way you can achieve what your want,

Comment: thanks for all, but I have too much textfield, if I use images for the all textfields, my application will run slowly.

Comment: Have you tried it? What makes you think drawing your own image is substantially slower than the built-in frame (which is, I believe, a 9-part image)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using an image.

`myTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue-line.png"];`

Comment: but this is background image..Can I change bottom border line color?

Comment: No, there isn't another way to do it.